# ASP.NET Core not connecting to database on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2016-express

I published my ASP.NET Core application to a Windows Server 2012 environment. I made a new website, pointed it to the folder and it was running fine. Now I am trying to make the application connect to a database. I installed SQL Server Express 2016 and edit my project so it retrieves data from the database. put my 'KSP_Backend.mdf' file to my server and I attached the file in SQL Server Management Studio. The database is completely visible, so it exists.

Now, when I try to run my project in my published project folder 'dotnet KSP_Backend.dll', it gives me the following error:

```
     Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
        A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to SQL Server. 
    The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider:SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Thespecified LocalDB instance does not exist.)
```

This is the connection string in the 'appsettings.json' file I used:

```
"Server=<My server's name>\\KSPSERVER;Database=KSP_Backend;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I'm just not sure anymore if the connection string caused my error. My firewall is off and LocalDB is up and running.

Comment: What are your SQL Server name when you connect to it via Management Studio? `<My server's name>\KSPSERVER` or simply `<My server's name>` or maybe `<My server's name>\SQLExpress`? Server name in connection string should match.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I didn't have 'Remote connection' enabled on the DataBase's Server.
In SQL Management Studio, right click the Server name, then `Properties`, go to tab `Connections`, make sure that `Allow remote connections` is enabled.

Another thing could be that the SQL Server TCP/IP protocol is not enabled.
In `SQL Server Configuration Manager`, click on `SQL Server Network Configuration` in the left pane and right-click `TCP/IP` and select `Enable`.

Finally, you might need to configure SQL Server Express to listen to a static port. You can find a good reference for this and the previous points here: [SQL Express Remote Connections](https://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/).